# gradle generated files fail to compile

Tags: java, gradle, javac, javacc

I am trying to get a JavaCC plugin working properly with Gradle. The plugin generates `.java` files correctly, but then during the `compileJavaC` task it crashes and burns with `cannot find symbol` errors. My JavaCC `.jj` file contains code that references other java files that are not generated, and I am guessing that the `compileJava` task tries to compile the generated code without providing a reference to the non-generated code.

Here is a minimum breaking example. build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

//compile .jj file in src/main/javacc
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'ca.coglinc', name: 'javacc-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'javacc'
```

src/main/MyClass.java:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(){

    }
}
```

and src/main/javacc/MyParser.jj:

```
options
{}
PARSER_BEGIN(MyParser)
import java.util.*;
public class MyParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    }
}
PARSER_END(MyParser)

SKIP:
{
    " "
}

TOKEN:
{
     <ANYTHING:  ~[]>
}


void production():
{}
{
    (<ANYTHING>)+
}
```

Running `gradle build` gives the following:

```
gradle build
:compileJavacc
Java Compiler Compiler Version 5.0 (Parser Generator)
(type "javacc" with no arguments for help)
Reading from file C:\Users\Nate Glenn\Desktop\java_workspace\test-gradle-javacc\
src\main\javacc\MyParser.jj . . .
File "TokenMgrError.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "ParseException.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "Token.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
File "SimpleCharStream.java" does not exist.  Will create one.
Parser generated successfully.
:compileJavaC:\Users\Nate Glenn\Desktop\java_workspace\test-gradle-javacc\build\
generated\javacc\MyParser.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        ^
  symbol:   class MyClass
  location: class MyParser
C:\Users\Nate Glenn\Desktop\java_workspace\test-gradle-javacc\build\generated\ja
vacc\MyParser.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
                         ^
  symbol:   class MyClass
  location: class MyParser
2 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.002 secs
```

How can I fix my Gradle build file so that `javaCompileC` correctly includes non-generated files when compiling the generated files?

Comment: *cannot find symbol errors* typically mean that you haven't loaded the corresponding class

Comment: @blgt But you can't `import` a class in the default package. `import MyClass` throws errors because there has to be a dot in there. Besides, they are in the same package, so is there really a reason to import?

Comment: I meant that the log shows your script building in `src/main/javacc` but not in `src/main`. Also, they're not in the same folder, so they're not visible - in Java, subpackages are not included in superpackages. The "package hierarchy" structure exists purely for readability.

Comment: ^ the above was supposed to read *superpackages are not included in subpackages*. The point being, you have no way to import `MyClass` unless you also put `MyParser.java` in the same package

Comment: @blgt My actual application does not use the default package, so the import would not cause an error. The files are in the same declared package, but separate folders. Are you saying that there is no way for me to reference source files in one folder from source files in another?

Comment: TBH I haven't tried this out myself on windows, but AFAIK if filesystem structure and package structure don't correspond, it *should* produce some sort of error; even if it doesn't it would *probably* be considered bad practice. None of this explains why your gradle script doesn't log a compilation of `MyClass.java` though.

Comment: @blgth Since they're in different folders I figured it must have started with the JavaCC folder, failed and stopped. Thanks for your help. I think the proper thing to do is set a property on the plugin so that the generated files go into the same folder as the rest of the package they belong to.

Comment: Actually I just confirmed that javac doesn't care if they are in different folders. Give it the list of source files and it will compile them just fine.

Comment: Then you should see the the compilation in the gradle log. I'd suggest trying to build a custom build target with a dependency on the file generation.

Comment: I believe I know what is going on, and have filed an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/johnmartel/javaccPlugin/issues/2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe if you manually include the non generated files in the directory before running the script? (I don't use gradle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source tree for MyClass is incorrect. It should be src/main/java/MyClass.java. In gradle, just like maven, convention is that java files by default are in src/main/java, and since you're not overriding this in your build.gradle file, I assume this is just an error on your part. The plugin correctly adds the JavaCC output path to the compileJava task's classpath, so if you create your java classes in the correct path for the compileJava task, everything should be fine :)

Just tried your example this way and it works.

By the way, thanks for your contribution to the plugin.

Comment: Thanks! It works. This is my first Gradle project and I've never used Maven, so this was a big help to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just some additional FYI, if you would like to overwrite the compile path, here is how you would do it:

```
//customized source sets to over-write the default src/main/java path
sourceSets {
    main{
        java {
            srcDir 'Java Source'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'resources'
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'tests'
        }
    }
}
```